# what regex preg_match_all from this date 2018 October 22?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

what regex preg_match_all from this date `2018 October 22`  without "-"or "/" , but with " "?
I want preg_match_all with pattern like this `2018 October 22` , not like `2018-October-22` , and not like `2018/10/22`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the date the precise date you want or just an example, so "2020 June 3" would be acceptable?

Comment: yes , just "2020 June 3" @KenY-N

Comment: https://regex101.com

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/7BvMSk/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this `regex`

```
$date='2018-October-22';
$date2='2018/10/22';
$new_date=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', ' ', $date);
$new_date2=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', ' ', $date2);
print_r($new_date);

print_r($new_date2);
```

[Check output here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b59a420670cc8b8726b6b51c8e52af074b7b219)

Answer (score 0):

You want [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead. This should work:

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y F j', '2018 October 22'); // OK
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y F j', '2018-October-22'); // Fail
```

`!` means set unparsed fields to the corresponding portion of 1970/1/1 00:00; `j` is the day of the month with no leading zeros, `F` is the full month (so `Feb` is invalid) and `Y` is the year as a four-digit number.

Comment: Based on OPs question I think you want `'Y F j'`, not `'j F Y'`

Comment: @Nick Indeed; I've fixed and used OP's dates.